# Relate two arraylist in android

Tags: android

user can add items to cart and simultaneously an url will be fired and an json will be returned..user can add any number of products..each product has an unique product_id.now each product can have many suppliers..suppliers also have unique supplier_id..for all the items added into the cart supplier may be common for few..say we have 5products into cart and..supllier1(having unique id) supplies 3products and supplier2(having unique id) supplies 2products..now i have found out and added unique supplier_id's in a array list..in each json object there is a field called price..I have to add the prices for a unique supplier..so for 2suppliers 2 seperate prices will be shown..(1st for supplier1 by adding prices of 3products he supplies)and other for supplier2..
part of json is

```
   {
      "BasketItemID": "4455",
      "BasketID": "11",
      "ProductID": "12909",
      "Qty": "1",
      "SupplierID": "7",
      "Code": "END10-001",
      "Name": "ENDO STOPPERS (100)",

      "Price": "5.72",
      "GST": "0.64",
      "PriceGST": "6.36",
      "Brand": "DENT AMERICA",
      "Thumbnail": null,

    },
    {
      "BasketItemID": "4464",
      "BasketID": "11",
      "ProductID": "12914",
      "Qty": "1",
      "SupplierID": "7",
      "Code": "INS52-361",
      "Name": "AMALGAM GUN CVD 45' PLASTIC",

      "Price": "17.00",
      "GST": "1.70",
      "PriceGST": "18.70",
      "Brand": "LARIDENT",
      "Thumbnail": null,

    },
    {
      "BasketItemID": "4465",
      "BasketID": "11",
      "ProductID": "13863",
      "Qty": "1",
      "SupplierID": "5",
      "Code": "9516068",
      "Name": "Tofflemire Bands #3 0015 Pkt 12",

      "Price": "2.24",
      "GST": "0.22",
      "PriceGST": "2.47",
      "Brand": "Rand",
      "Thumbnail": null,

    },
```

so how can i add the prices?

Comment: This looks a huge question. can you simply it to read? Like what you want ? Why you have posted this JSON code here?

Comment: Which property is your actual price?

Comment: sorry for that..there is a tag in the json called price..

Comment: So you want to consume the JSON and sum prices?

Comment: wht is the problem, parsin json or?

Comment: yes add the prices for a particular supplier..

Comment: note that there are 2supplier ids 7 and 5

Answer (score 0):

If your problem revolves around parsing a JSON array you may want to check out the example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html). Then you would filter by supplier, feel free to let me expand if you want to make your requirements more explicit.

It would look something like this (not tested)

```
Integer id;
Map<Integer, Double> sums;
...
while (reader.hasNext()) {
   String name = reader.nextName();
   if (name.equals("SupplierID")) {
     id = reader.nextInt();
   } else if (name.equals("Price")) {
     if(!sums.containsKey(id)){
        sums.put(id, reader.nextDouble());
     }
     else{
       Double f = (Double) sums.get(id);
       sums.put(id, f+reader.nextDouble());
     }
   } else {
     reader.skipValue();
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to add the prices for supplier with supplier id 7..u may have a look at json.

Comment: So I need to be explicit? Did you look at the example?

Comment: Ok let me try to be more explicit

Comment: that will be fine and helpful.. @jackie.

Comment: That is the best I am going to be able to help you it is based on the example

Comment: It helped..bt i did it in a different way..I made a class of 2fields is and price..then made an arraylist of that class type..then checked whether that id exsist in a arraylist or not..if yes then only add the prices else add the id and the price as new class object.

Comment: but thnx for ur help @jackie..looking frwrd fr ur hlp nxt tym if i will b in a prblm..